# Laravel - How to import into two (2) tables using Laravel Maatwebsites

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

In my Laravel-5.8 and Maatwebsites-3.1, I have these two models:

HrEmployee (hr_employees): id, first_name, last_name, email
HrDepartment (hr_departments): id department_name

I have just one Excel sheet:

> First Name | Last Name | Official Email | Department

```
class FirstEmployeeSheetImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, WithBatchInserts, WithValidation
{
   protected $department;
   private $errors = []; // array to accumulate errors
   use Importable;

   public function model(array $row)
   {           
      $this->department = $row['department'];        
      $employee_data = [
        'first_name'                        => $row['first_name'],
        'last_name'                         => $row['last_name'],
        'email'                             => $row['official_email'],
        'department_id'                     => $this->getDepartment(),
     ];                
     $employee = HrEmployee::create($employee_data);                   
   }

   public function getDepartment(){
    if(!empty($this->department) || !$this->department){

        return HrDepartment::where('dept_name',$this->department)->where('company_id',Auth::user()->company_id)->pluck('id')->first();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
  }              
}
```

When the import button is submitted, I want the aplication to first check Department column in the Excel sheet, then insert into the department_name in the hr_departments table, before proceeding to import the other details into hr_employees (First Name | Last Name | Official Email | Department)

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Not elegant but you could just write two Importers.

Comment: @FloEspen - How? Can you give example from my code